# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "categories_posts" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to create a 'category' in my blog.There are two models `post` and `category`.I using habtm association

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

but when I check from the irb

```
post.categories
```

shell show me an error

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "categories_posts" does not exist
```

how fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create this join table use [create_join_table](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_join_table) in migrations. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#creating-join-tables-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations) is details.

Comment: in both tables?or only one?

Comment: `create_join_table` should be called in new migration file.